# Chai expect doesn't fail the test if it is inside a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

so this test no matter what I do, doesn't fail.

```
it("should not save the user(duplicate user)", function (done) {
        const user = {
            name: "faruk",
            email: "faruk@farukmail.com",
            password: "faruk2356",
        };
        model.saveUser(user, function (err, doc) {
            expect(err).to.exist;
            done()
        });
    });
```

If I `Console.log` the error it shows this:

```
AssertionError: expected null to exist.
```

So there is an error but the test doesn't fail. and the errors isn't even related to the save user function it's the error that chai throws. how is that even possible when I `console.log(err)` it logs not the error callback gives but the error chai throws. I can't understand what is going on here.

Comment: Running into the same problem. What makes this even weirder is that changing the check to some literal, like `expect("abc").to.be.null` triggers correctly. But the variable like `expect(err).to.be.null` does not.

Comment: (just in case, yes, I'm sure it's that change only, because both `to.be.null` and `to.not.be.null` don't trigger for a variable, but do for "abc")

Answer (score 0):

You are using callback style, and it seems it doesn’t throw an error; instead returns as an `error object.` That's why it doesn’t fail.

```js
var chai = require("chai")
var expect = chai.expect;

it("should not save the user(duplicate user)", function (done) {
    const user = {
        name: "faruk",
        email: "faruk@farukmail.com",
        password: "faruk2356",
    };

    model.saveUser(user, function (err, doc) {
        expect(err).to.be.null
// or check if an error exists and throw it
        if(err)
           throw err

          done()
    });

});

var model = {
    saveUser: (user, callback) => {
        // user save function
        callback(new Error('Unable to save user'))
    }
}
```

Or, you can throw the error inside the saveUser function.

```js
var chai = require("chai")
var expect = chai.expect;

it("should not save the user(duplicate user)", function (done) {
    const user = {
        name: "faruk",
        email: "faruk@farukmail.com",
        password: "faruk2356",
    };

    model.saveUser(user, function (err, doc) {
        done()
    });

});

var model = {
    saveUser: (user, callback) => {
        try {
            // user save function
            throw new Error('Save user failed')
        }
        catch (e ){
            throw e
            // throw an error instead passing it to callback
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **assert** with chai instead it provides the **notEqual** method for checking double equals *(==)* and **strictNotEqual** for triple equals *(===)*

You can also write tests using assertions like isNull

```
const chai = require("chai");
const assert = chai.assert;

suite("User", () => {
  const USER_SAVE_ERROR_MSG = 'User exists already';

  const model = {
    saveUser: (user, callback) => {
      // user save function
      callback(new Error(USER_SAVE_ERROR_MSG))
    }
  }

  it("should not save the user(duplicate user)", (done) => {
    const user = {
      name: "faruk",
      email: "faruk@farukmail.com",
      password: "faruk2356",
    };

    model.saveUser(user, function(err, doc) {
      // use assert.equal instead of assert.notEqual to fail the test
      assert.notEqual(err, null); 
      // following works equally well
      // assert.isNotNull(err);  --> use assert.isNull to fail the test 
      assert.strictEqual(err.message, USER_SAVE_ERROR_MSG)
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `saveUser` is not failing which leads to the `err` to not be `null` and the assertion itself is failing because you expect it to be something else than `null` or `undefined` as you are using `.exists`.